# How do you extend the MembershipUser class?

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, asp.net-2.0

I want the class inheritance to look like this...

Person -> MembershipUser -> User

Person & User are my own classes. What is the syntax in ASP.NET 2.0 for MembershipUser to inherit my Person class. If I have to create a new class that first inherits MembershipUser, then I have the problem of double inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the articles that MSDN has on [Implementing a Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) and the [MembershipProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx)?

There are some very detailed articles there that will help you get started on implementing your own membership user.

Happy coding!

-Frinny